# OneM2M: IPE that periodically fetches device data from FTP server

Tags: ftp, sftp, iot, onem2m

I have a device that sends data to a FTP server. In oneM2M, I want to implement an IPE to access this data and send it to MN-CSE.

I am thinking of periodically (say every 5 minutes) requesting the FTP server and fetching the data to the IPE which further processes and sends this data to MN-CSE. I just wanted to confirm if the approach is fine or are there any better ways to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question more related to the infrastructure architecture you are planing to deploy. It is feasible, of course, but polling has the disadvantage that if the delay is to small your AE would poll the ftp server unnecessarily often, and if it is to long then you might miss data delivered by your device (to the ftp server). Alternatives could be:

- The ftp server notifies your AE
- Your AE implements the ftp server and would then be able to directly react on new data events.